# Cannot Fetch Data From Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having a problem fetching a showing data from firestore in my app.

When I start the app I get the error:

> Cannot find a different supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'.

This is the post.component.html
`<div *ngFor= "let p of posts$"| async>`

post.component.ts

```
export class PostsComponent {
    posts$;
    constructor(private createPostService: CreatePostService) {
        this.posts$ = this.createPostService.get();
    }
}
```

this is the post service

```
get() {
    return this.db.collection('posts');
}
```

Comment: Probably this variable `posts$` is not an array, `ngFor` can only iterate arrays, check if it is an array. If it is an array, can you please also post the value of `posts$``

Comment: As Sameer mentioned, is very likely that your "posts$" var is not an iterate array, check this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49084550/7806223 and confirm that is an array object. Also, double check that your service is returning data (a console log perhaps), it feels like you are doing all of this on Angular without connecting to any backend. Let me know if you are able to confirm both of those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with different approach while saving and loading data to and from Firestore. I am working with Ionic 4 development in Angular and the structure of the application is similar to yours.

My approach of storing data and loading data from Firestore database:

**In: post.component.ts**

1. Declare the interface type that I want to store data as. This is declared right bellow the import methods in the beginning of the file:

```
export interface Post {
  pid:string, //This is the post's ID
  uid:string, //User's ID that has posted the post 
  message:string, // This is the post's content
  timestamp:number, // This is the post's date and time
} // This is just brief data for the example
```

2. Then you have to declare a public variable as array of type Post, that so you load all the posts there before previewing. Then within the constructor load the data and save them in the array:

```
    posts:Post[] = [];
    constructor([...]) {
        [...]
        //Load posts based on criteria:
        // USER_ID is a known user id.
        this.firestore.collection('posts').ref.where('uid', '==', USER_ID)
         .onSnapshot( (querySnapshot) => {
      
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

          // Found a single snapshot.
          // Get the data and push to the array

          this.posts.push(
           { 
            pid: doc.data().pid,
            uid: doc.data().uid, 
            message: doc.data().message, 
            timestamp: doc.data().timestamp, 
           }
         );
        
      });
      
    });
}
// This is just an example on how to query data, you can use your code to just load all the posts.
```

**In: post.component.html**

3. After that you can list the data in the html file as you did, but remove the `$` sign:

```
<div *ngFor="let p of posts">
Post ID: {{p.pid}}
Post message: {{p.message}} 
</div>
```

4. The data should be previewed as follows ***This is an example for 2 loaded posts***:

```
Post ID: THE_ID_OF_LOADED_POST_01
Post message: This is the message of post 01
Post ID: THE_ID_OF_LOADED_POST_02
Post message: This is the message of post 02
```

Again, all those is a working example, so you can modify the data according to your needs. I hope that this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase provides two types of databases. 
1) Realtime Database
2) Cloud Firestore

If you are using Realtime Database. The below code will help you

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TasksService {

  tasksList : AngularFireList<any>;

  constructor(private tasksdb : AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getTa`enter code here`sks() {
    this.tasksList = this.tasksdb.list('tasks');
    return this.tasksList;
  }
}
```

If you are using Cloud Firestore, this will help you

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

export class PolicyService {
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  getPolicies() {
    return this.firestore.collection('policies').snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

But make sure that you have imported all the required firebase modules in the root module.

Comment: still not working same problem ... i have used the Cloud Firestore